how to add cors origin in public folder laravel
Access to font at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/webfont.woff' from origin 'http://localhost:8001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I have two websites one is 'http://localhost:8001' core html and another is 'http://localhost:8000' laravel, in laravel public folder I have css and font files. css doesnot give me cors error but loading font file give me cors error.
I have added following code in haccess still giving cors error
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

I have added public path in config cors by /*
'paths' => ['/*','api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

I want to load in html page with fonts and css from api using javascript. Api return html view for http://localhost:8001 page

"I have added public path in config cors by /*" - that should have no relevance for static assets, that are not actually served by Laravel to begin with, but directly by the web server.

any idea how to add cross origin in public asset
